# Alter the first 20 lines of a gzipped file without rewriting the entire file in BASH

Tags: bash, file-io, gzip

I have 305 files. Each is ~10M lines. I only need to alter the first 20 lines of each file.

Specifically I need to add # as the first char of the first 18 Lines, delete the 19th line (but safer to say, delete all lines that are completely blank, and replace > with # on the 20th line.

The remaining 9.9999999M lines dont need to change at all.

If the files were not gzipped, I could do something like:

```
while read F; do
    for i in $(seq 1 100); do 
        awk '{gsub(/#/,"##"); print $0}' $F
        awk more commands
        awk more commnds
    done
done < "$FNAMES"
```

but what is really throwing a wrench is the fact the files are all gzipped. Is there any way to efficiently alter these 20 lines without unzipping and / or rewriting the whole file?

Comment: zcat them, then gzip back.

Comment: Im sorry, I dont understand. The last sentence of my post says " Is there any way to efficiently alter these 20 lines without unzipping and / or rewriting the whole file?" ... I am asking if this is the only way to do this, not that it can be done. I know that it can be done. Thanks very much.

Comment: and unzipping/rezipping is not too bad if you do it while processing and not beforehand.

Comment: And no, I dont think you can alter a zipped file in any meaningful and efficient way.

Comment: I am also interested to know , what you think you will gain by just altering the top of the file. because it will very probably lead to large parts of the file being rewritten to disk, since you are adding characters. (depending on the filesystem). I would understand if you were just modifying some characters, then it would be a lot more efficient to edit in place.

Comment: It will enable these files to be indexed by a third party algorithm

Comment: Not unzipping them will enable them to be indexed?

Comment: Yes, please see Tabix, which is part of a package of tools called SAMTOOLS

Comment: yes, looking at tabix and bgzip , I would just decompress, sed/awk,recompress. That would be the only option unless bgzip somehow has an ability to "patch" the bgzipped file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. With adaptive compression schemes (such as the Lempel-Ziv system gzip uses), it adjusts the encoding based on what it sees as it goes through the file. This means that the way the end of the file gets compressed (and hence decompressed) depends on the beginning of the file. If you change just the beginning of the (compressed) file, you'll change how the end gets decompressed, essentially corrupting the file.

So decompressing, modifying, and recompressing is the only way to do it.